# TWSz Java API restart and restartAndCleanUp job in plan

Tags: java, workload-scheduler, tivoli-work-scheduler

I'm looking for an example how to restart and restart and clean up job in Plan using TWSz Java API. For simple restart I'm changing status of a job

```
plan.setJobInstanceStatus(jobInPlanList.get(0).getId(), FlowNodeInternalStatusType.FLOW_NODE_ZOSSTATUS_READY, "", null);
```

I don't know that this is correct way to do that? And I can;t find the way to restart and clean up, I tried to use combination:

```
plan.beginJobRestartCleanup
plan.executeJobRestartCleanup
plan.commitJobRestartAndCleanup
```

But nothing works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for simple restart is ok to set job status to ready.
Concerning restart and clean up, you should use the following flow:
-set RestartCleanupOptions parameter that you need to pass to beginJobRestartCleanup api
-modify job to be restarted, if needed
-commit
-handle possible exception using a try-catch block and rollbackJobRestartCleanup

Here is an example:

```
    try
    {
        /*
         * start the cleanup session, modify parameters if needed
         */
        RestartCleanupOptions rco = new RestartCleanupOptions();
        rco.setAction(RestartCleanupType.ACTION_JOBRERUN);
        rco.setCleanup(CleanUpOption.MANUAL);
        rco.setUseExpandedJCL(false);
        plan.beginJobRestartCleanup(restartID, rco, null);


        /*
         * Now get datasets lists for the specified restart step
         */
        List datasetList = plan.getJobDataSets(restartID, null);

        /* Here you can modify datasetList if needed*/

        /*
         * Now set the datasets
         */
        plan.setJobDataSets(restartID, datasetList, null);
        /*
         * Now get the JCL
         */
        JobControlLanguage jcl = plan.getJobJCL(restartID, true, null);

        /* Here you can modify jcl if needed*/

        /*
         * Now set the JCL
         */
        plan.setJobJCL(restartID, jcl, true, null);
        /*
         * Execute the step-restart operation
         */
        plan.executeJobRestartCleanup(restartID, "JCL", null, null, null);
        /*
         * commit the step restart phase
         */
        plan.commitJobRestartAndCleanup(JobInPlan.class, restartID, null);

    }
    catch (ConnException e)
    {
        plan.rollbackJobRestartAndCleanup(JobInPlan.class, restartID, null);
    }
```

I hope this will be helpful.